# Issue in hiding UINavigationBar in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uisplitviewcontroller, navigationbar

I have a split view controller in my app's contact page.. and i am unable to hide the navigation bar in my page.. Can anyone help me on hiding the navigationBar. i have attached my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
splitViewController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 

[super viewDidLoad];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    [[VHeaderView sharedVHeaderView] viewWithCommonHeaderOnView1:self.view];
}
else
{
    [[VHeaderView_iPad sharedVHeaderView_iPad] viewWithCommonHeaderOnView1:self.view];

}

[splitViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,48, 768, 1024)];
  // [self.view removeFromSuperview];
//self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,100, 768, 1024);
[self.view addSubview:splitViewController.view];


}
```

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}                       put this method in .m file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

put this code in your .m file
```

if u don't wish to animated effect then set no.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. works for me.  Make sure that navigation controller is allocated.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];  
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Callled only once this method.

try to put your code in ViewWillAppear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];

}
```

try this code